# iOS for all screens and orientations

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I Build my iOS Apps programmatically, I tried using the storyboard, constraints are buggy and the storyboard takes a long time to compile to see the results, so now i do all the interface programmatically, it works well for 4,4s,5,5s,6,6s,6P,6PS

but the problem that my client now asked for an app that should work in phones using portrait and for iPads using landscape, the programmatically method works for me very well for phones, now I make a separate storyboard for iPad for my app or what?

if you need more info I can elaborate with images, I'm looking forward for your help.

Comment: What are you asking exactly, how to transform an iPhone app to be a universal app ?

Answer (score 2):

In deploy info, you should choose devices is Universal. And then each device you can choose portrait or landscape.

**For example:**

For iPhone devices: See the screen. 
[image]

For iPad devices that supporting landscape. See the screen. 
[image]

Moreover, in file info.plist you should add some key like image.

[image]

I think my solution help you solving this problem.

Comment: I think you mean underneath instead of above because your images are being displayed after the text, other than that, good answer.

Comment: Thank @EmilioPelaez for your comment.

Comment: i have it as universal of course, 
but the app is portrait only for phones & (both portrait and landscape for ipad)

so i ask, now i make another storyboard for iPad ?

Comment: Of course, if the design for iPad differences with iPhone version you should create a new storyboard. Then in your code your add some line for check. For example:  if(iphone_version){//load storyboard iphone} else {//load storyboard iPad}.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep using the programmatically approach,but to handle portrait on iphone and landscape on ipad,you must configure your info.plist file like this:

[image: orientation at launch]